# I want to run multiple functions using one function to do them all! any ideas?

Tags: javascript

```
function master() {
   moveEyes();
   monenoses();
   moveears();
   movefaces();
   movelips();
   moveglasses();
}
```

Above is all the functions i want to run from moveEyes to moveglasses. Function master is what i was going to call the main function. All the other functions work individually buy a bit a text like this:

```
// <p><a href="javascript:moveEyes()">Move to next pair of eyes</a></p>
```

But instead of having one line for each, I want one for all.

I tried doing what I have done at the top and then having one line like above but for the master function but it only moves the first line of moveEyes.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled `monenoses`.
Therefore, your function calls `moveEyes`, then throws an exception and stops.

You should use a debugging tool like Firebug or Chrome's Developer Tools, which will show these errors.

Comment: LOL im embarrassed can't believe i didnt see that! im just going to try it fingers crossed. thanks aswell

Answer (score 1):

`<p><a href="javascript:master()">Do all</a></p>` should work.

It is most likely an error with one of your other functions that's causing the code to halt. Perhaps you should check your Javascript Console.

Comment: i just said above that the code you've got written there i've done already! what sort of error are you thinking?

Comment: I know you did. I was just repeating you saying that it should work. I know you've already figured it out, but the javascript console would be able to tell you something along the lines of "Function not found" and include the line number.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to reduce lines of code (just make sure you edit arr):

```
<script>

  function hi(){
    alert('hi');
  }

  function bye(){
    alert("bye");
  }

  var arr = ["hi", "bye"]
  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
   window[arr[i]]();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: **No!** Don't use `eval`!  `window[arr[i]]()`.

Comment: I recommend that eval is not used. I like this blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx